# $I - H$ is a projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, projection-matrices

Let $H$ be a projection matrix onto a subspace $V$ i.e. $Im(H)=V$. Show that $I - H$ is a projection matrix onto the subspace $V^\perp$.

I already have shown that $(I-H)^T=(I-H)=(I-H)^2$. I still need to show that $Im(I-H)=Im(H)^\perp$. I actually already have a proof of this statement using eigenvalues but I really want to do it the brutal way

I managed to do this inclusion  $Im(I-H)\subseteq Im(H)^\perp$, but I struggle to show the reverse inclusion. I tried to pick $y \in Im(H)^\perp$, so that $\langle y,Hx \rangle$ $\forall x$ and I need to show that there exists $z \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $y=(I-H)z$. I squeezed the inner product equality I have in many ways but still cannot find something interesting. I also tried to pick different choices of $x$ but nothing came out. Any ideas to solve this ?

Comment: You have to assume that the matrix $H$ is self-adjoint in the complex case or symmetric in the real case.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc a projection matrix is symmetric by definition if I am not mistaken

Comment: For me a projection matrix by definition satisfies $H^2=H.$ An orthogonal projection matrix by definition satisfies $H^*=H$ additionally. In two dimensional space you can project at an angle different from $\pi/2.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc For me and for wikipedia, a matrix that satisfies $H^2=H$ is an called idempotent matrix. It is a projection matrix if we add the assumption of symmetry. Anyway its maybe a just a difference in literature

Comment: It is not crucial but Wikipedia follows [my way](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra))

Comment: Weird, I think that's a "projection" which is different from "projection matrix", where the symmetry is necessary as you can see in the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix#Properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\langle y,Hx\rangle=0$ for all $x$, then
$$
\langle Hy,Hy\rangle=\langle y,H^\ast Hy\rangle=\langle y,H^2y\rangle=\langle y,Hy\rangle=0.
$$
Therefore $Hy=0$. In turn, $y=Hy+(I-H)y=(I-H)y\in\operatorname{Im}(I-H)$.

Comment: Seems good to me